# Can't connect pgadmin to the server

Tags: node.js, pgadmin

I'm  trying to connect my server (based on node.js) with db from pgAdmin.<>
However I keep getting '${PORT}', instead of PORT's value in env file :

[image]

pgAdmin part:

[image]

index.js file:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require ('express')
const sequelize = require('./db')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
const app = express()
const start = async () => {
try {
    await sequelize.authenticate()
    await sequelize.sync()
    app.listen(PORT,()=>console.log('Server started on port ${PORT}'))
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
}
start()
```

db.js:

```
const {Sequelize} = require('sequelize')
module.exports = new Sequelize(
process.env.DB_NAME,
process.env.DB_USER,
process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
{
   dialect:'postgres',
   host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT
}
)
```

.env file:

```
PORT=7000
DB_NAME=postgres
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASSWORD='Ondj8_oP1sw'
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
```

package.json:

```
"name": "server",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"dev": "nodemon index.js"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"dotenv": "^16.0.1",
"express": "^4.18.1",
"pg": "^8.8.0",
"pg-hstore": "^2.3.4",
"sequelize": "^6.21.4"
```

},
"devDependencies": {
"nodemon": "^2.0.19"
}
}

Comment: Your connection with postgresql is fine. The ${PORT} in the `console.log` is actually the port of the express app, which is 7000 in your .env. And the way you log an variable in console.log is't correct, try change to:  `console.log(\`Server started on port ${PORT}\`)`. with the character is \` instead of '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual connection should be fine, yet your console.log should look like `` console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`) ``, use back ticks `` if you want to console.log a variable.